# Writing out a Maple-integrated Function does not work as intended

Tags: integration, functions, gamma-function, maple

I think I have a basic problem with how Maple handles functions. Here's what I do:

I used the Function `KummerM` (https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Kummer) without any problems, but for specific reasons I need to use the integral representation:

$$
M(a, b, z) =  \frac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a)} \int_0^1 e^{zu} u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-a-1}\, du ~~~~~ (1)
$$

It turns out that Maple doesn't do what I want:

```
> evalb(GAMMA(b)*(int(u^(a-1)*(1-u)^(b-a-1)*e^(z*u), u = 0 .. 1))/(GAMMA(a)*GAMMA(b-a)) = KummerM(a, b, z));
                             false

KummerMint := (a, b, z) ->  GAMMA(b)*(int(u^(a-1)*(1-u)^(b-a-1)*e^(z*u), u = 0 .. 1))/(GAMMA(a)*GAMMA(b-a));


> evalb(KummerMint(1, 2, 1) = Malt(1, 2, 1));
                             false
```

Meaning that $(1)$ is not true :-/

Does anyone see the error?

Much appreciated!

bm

Comment: `e^(z*u)` it should be: `exp(z*u)`

Answer (score 1):

For me works fine.

`kernelopts(version)#Maple 2020.1, X86 64 WINDOWS, Jun 10 2020, Build ID 1474787`

Try:

`f := (a, b, z) -> GAMMA(b)*int(exp(z*u)*u^(a - 1)*(1 - u)^(b - 1 - a), u = 0 .. 1)/(GAMMA(a)*GAMMA(b - a)); evalf(f(1, 2, 1)); evalf(KummerM(1, 2, 1)); evalf(f(2, 3, 2)); evalf(KummerM(2, 3, 2));`

Answer (score 1):

The `evalb` command is most certainly not the appropriate command for comparing two forms mathematically.

Often the `is` command is more appropriate. But for this example some extra conversions are needed to help it along -- after which the ratio of both sides of the equation can be simplified symbolically to 1.

```
restart;
eq := Int(u^(a-1)*(1-u)^(b-a-1)*exp(z*u), u=0..1)
      * GAMMA(b)/(GAMMA(a)*GAMMA(b-a))
      = KummerM(a, b, z):

new1 := convert(combine(eq),compose,LaguerreL,GAMMA):
new2 := convert(new1, LaguerreL, "raise b"):

simplify(expand(value((rhs/lhs)(new2))));
                           1
```